# calculate date+1 if time is greater in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to calculate date with some condition.

dataframe:

```
    ID      PID PDate       
1   BBBBBB  A12 20210512T165301.046    
2   BBBBBB  A12 20210511T055001.199    
3   CCCCCC  B11 20210512T105805.685
```

If Pdate time is greater than 4 PM then add one to date and if time is less than 9:30 AM then subtract one to the date. Date is given in 24 hours format and time is mentioned after character T.
For example 20210512T165301.046 , here time is 1653 which is greater than 4 PM so it has to be 20210513.

The days are business days. if current day is Friday, then next day is monday and if current day is monday, previous day is friday.
I have to exclude holidays as well.

```
Expected:
    ID      PID PDate       
1   BBBBBB  A12 20210513  
2   BBBBBB  A12 20210510 
3   CCCCCC  B11 20210512
```

between.time gives only the range between 9:30-4 and I do not know how to get previous day and next day resp.

Can anyone please help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding hours after convert to date time with `pd.to_datetime`

```
df.PDate = pd.to_datetime(df.PDate)
c1 = df.PDate.dt.time<datetime.time(9,30,0)
c2 = df.PDate.dt.time>datetime.time(16,00,0)
df['new_date'] = np.select([c1,c2], [df.PDate.dt.date.apply(lambda x: x - BDay(1)), df.PDate.dt.date.apply(lambda x: x + BDay(1))],default=df.PDate)
df
       ID  PID                   PDate                new_date
1  BBBBBB  A12 2021-05-12 16:53:01.046 2021-05-13 00:00:00.000
2  BBBBBB  A12 2021-05-11 05:50:01.199 2021-05-10 00:00:00.000
3  CCCCCC  B11 2021-05-12 10:58:05.685 2021-05-12 10:58:05.685
```

Comment: thank you will try this.. I forgot to mention that it has to be business days. If current day is friday, then next day is monday  and if current day is monday , previous day will be friday.

Comment: thank you very much  it works fine . I have to learn more of lambda and select operations in pandas.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `np.select`

First convert `PDate` to pandas datetime, then create datetime for one day, then create boolean masking for your required conditions i.e. 9:30 which is (9*60+30 minutes), and 4:00 PM (Which is 16*60 minutes), and add/subtract one day based on this boolean maskings.

```py
df['PDate'] = pd.to_datetime(df['PDate'])
oneDay = pd.to_timedelta(1,unit='d')
df['PDate'] = np.select([(df['PDate'].dt.minute+df['PDate'].dt.hour*60)<(9*60+30),(df['PDate'].dt.minute+df['PDate'].dt.hour*60)<(16*60)],
                        [df['PDate'] - oneDay, df['PDate'] + oneDay], 
                        df['PDate']
                        )
```

**OUTPUT:**

```py
       ID  PID                   PDate
1  BBBBBB  A12 2021-05-12 16:53:01.046
2  BBBBBB  A12 2021-05-10 05:50:01.199
3  CCCCCC  B11 2021-05-13 10:58:05.685
```

Eventually, you can use `strftime` to change the format of the resulting `PDate` values.

Answer (score 0):

```
df['new_date'] = df['PDate'].apply(lambda x : int(x[:8])+1
                  if int(x[9:13]) > 1600
                  else (int(x[:8])-1 if int(x[9:13]) < 930
                  else int(x[:8]))
                  )
```

Is it right?